# Saving UIView's transition as a GIF

Tags: ios, gif, animated-gif, cgimage

I am facing quite interesting task. My goal is to pick 2 images from Photo Album, add transition from one picture to another (like kCATransitionPush or kCATransitionFade), and store the whole animation in GIF file.

I managed to make most of the task work, except for storing transition animation in GIF.
The app is currently able to save GIF file made of 2 images, with the specific duration between showing the images.

As for storing the transition animation within GIF File, I have an idea that I would like to consult with you:

It is based on creating custom transition, that will work in a following manner. (Lets assume that I will have to create custom transition for each type of transition, and that we will use Fade transition in the following example):

1. Split the single Fade animation into ex. 20 smaller animations, and create the still frame after each animation
2. Organize previously created still frames into a GiF.

Pros:
-probably will work

Cons:
- no transparency
- every transformation need to be recreated manually, and you cant use default transformations

I will be very grateful for any tips connected with the described task. If it happens that one is able to extract animation frames, I will be extremely grateful for the right documentation/tutorial link.

Best regards